# JSON DecodeError

Tags: python, json

With my code:

```
import json


filename = 'SASbonus_data.json'
with open(filename) as f:
    traveler = json.load(f)

print(traveler)
```

I get the error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This usually means that your json file is not valid, try copy-pasting it to some json-validating site online to check that

Comment: are you able to share the json file?